# MDX where Date is less than now

Tags: mdx, cube

This is my code below......

```
    SELECT 
 {
    [Measures].[ACPPurchaseValue]

  } ON COLUMNS
,(

   [Date].[YYYYMMDD].[YYYYMMDD]

  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Kahuna]
WHERE  
  (
    [Reporting Currency].[reportingCurrency].&[1]
   ,strToSet(@MdxBOSP)
   ,strToSet(@MdxVIPType)
   ,strToSet(@MdxHost)
   ,strToSet(@MdxOperatorName)
  );
```

How can I say where [Date].[YYYYMMDD].[YYYYMMDD] < getdate()

Comment: You can't say this : `[Date].[YYYYMMDD].[YYYYMMDD] < getdate()` ...you have different types on either side of `<`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initially create a member, or a single member set, that corresponds to today.

The following looks a little complex but is actually a fairly standard approach - put forward by Tomislav Piasevoli - it is against the `AdvWrks` dimension `Date`:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now()
     ,'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today] + ']' 
  SET [Today] AS 
    StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string]
     ,constrained
    ) 
...
```

So applying to your situation:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Key for Today] AS 
    Format
    (
      Now()
     ,'yyyyMMdd'
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today string] AS 
    '[Date].[YYYYMMDD].[YYYYMMDD].&[' + [Measures].[Key for Today] + ']' 
  SET [Today] AS 
    StrToMember
    (
      [Measures].[Today string]
     ,constrained
    ) 
SELECT 
   [Measures].[ACPPurchaseValue] ON 0
  ,{null:[Today].item(0).item(0)}  ON 1
FROM [Kahuna]
WHERE  
  (
    [Reporting Currency].[reportingCurrency].&[1]
   ,strToSet(@MdxBOSP)
   ,strToSet(@MdxVIPType)
   ,strToSet(@MdxHost)
   ,strToSet(@MdxOperatorName)
  );
```

Two other better solutions which could simplify life for everyone:

1. Do not materialize future dates in your cube
2. Leave future dates in, but add a custom set called `[Today]` and a calculated member called today as a child to Date's All member.

Comment: It will be much more simple and performant if you just add a IsPastDate flag as a new attribute in your date dimension.

Comment: Cheers @GregGalloway : the cubes I get to play with have no future dates.

Comment: Hi whytheq, I think this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479968/mdx-where-date-is-less-than-now

Comment: Please have a look at this, I was trying to solve this  problem , but could not.